# Chrome extension transfer to manifest 2 - No ajax response

Tags: json, google-chrome, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Hayush!
Been trying to transfer my Chrome extension to manifest 2. Everything is working except for one script which calls an ajax. I have a variable that contains a JSON content which needs to be transferred to the server.

```
function sendlist(list){

jsontext = JSON.stringify(list);

$.ajax({
        url: amfurl + "user/listbookmarks/",
            dataType: 'text json',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
            data: {'folders': jsontext}, 

        success: function(data){
            $('#importing').css('display','none');
            $('#importdone').css('display','block');
            console.log(data);      
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
}
});  
}
```

For some reason the ajax part is not executed at all. No error message was triggered, nor in the server error log.

All of the inline scripts and scripts in general were included in the popup.js. So it's probably not the issue.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

The following code works perfectly on previous manifest

```
function importbookmarks(){
$('#formadd').css('display','none');
$('#importing').css('display','block');
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'chromextension','importbookmarks', username]);
 chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function(bookmarks) {
        sendlist(bookmarks);
   });
}


function sendlist(list){
jsontext = JSON.stringify(list);
$.ajax({
        url: amfurl + "user/listbookmarks/",
            dataType: 'text json',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
    //  processData: false,
            data: {'folders': jsontext}, 

        success: function(data){
            $('#importing').css('display','none');
            $('#importdone').css('display','block');
            console.log(data);

        }
});  
}
```

Comment: Don't use eval, but `JSON.parse` (eval is forbidden by the default CSP). Any change that you're doing a JSONP request instead of JSON? Did you request the host permissions in the manifest file?

Comment: Replaced the eval with JSON.parse. Applied jsonp:false above the async and the page is set in the permission. Seems like it doesn't perform the ajax at all. Other scripts on the page do work.

Comment: Did you mean to use `bookmarks` instead of `jsonlist` in your last comment?

Comment: Did you really not get any errors? Not even a warning about the Content Security Policy..? You need to inspect the popup for the console.

Comment: nothing, inspected the popup and everything. Tried also printing it directly and alerts.

Comment: That's odd, check if your extension follows all of the guidelines stated in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't with the function. The button execution wasn't calling it correctly. 
Here is the code I used to get the function to work in manifest 2

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById("import-bookmarks").addEventListener("click", function () {
        importbook();return;
    });
```